# C++ - How to break when the number of references to a shared pointer change?

Tags: visual-c++, boost, shared-ptr, weak-references, strong-references

In Microsoft Visual C++ 2015, how can I set a "Data Breakpoint" on a Boost shared pointer so that the debugger breaks whenever the number of strong and/or weak references changes?

Answer (score 2):

The control block of a `std::shared_ptr`in VS2015 has `_Uses`and `_Weaks` members. Just set data breakpoints to these through their watch expressions: e.g. `&(*(ptr)._Rep)._Weaks`

Here's a screenshot:

[image: VS 2015 shared_ptr control block debug view]